# contacts app makes calls with a voip app instead of normal phone app

Tags: contacts, permissions, voip

I installed a voip app, Talkatone, and now Contacts always use Talkatone instead of making normal phone call. Any workaround? Sometimes I would like to place normal call, because Talkatone is not making call to some numbers. Android Go Edition.

Curiosly, Fongo app, another voip, allows one use Contacts within app, but does make call itself, not through Talkaton, like regular Phone app. Regretfully Fongo sms messages are not free.

Comment: Is Talkatone set as the default phone app?

Comment: Do not know, perhaps. Should I install some default app configuration utility and change it back to phone?